# Amazon Web Service : Certificate Manager SSL Workaround

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, apache2

I have set up an EC2 instance. Logged in with server and set up apache2 in it.

Example Domain: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Created Route53 for example.com and pointed NS record to Domain provider. So, I am going to use Route53 for DNS.

In DNS, I have created A record with EC2 IP.

In apache2 set up VirtualHost for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), Reloaded apache2 server, and also enable site [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Now, I have purchased a certificate from the AWS certificate manager for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I have added the CNAME record in Route53 and also validated the domain. The certificate was also activated.

Now, I am going to hit the site [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), It's redirecting to https://www.example.com but the page is giving an error regarding HTTPS.

I have also opened 443 port for that instance.

Comment: explain "not working".

Comment: @Riz Updated questions, Site domain is not working ith https.

Comment: Can you update the question with your set up? Do you have this EC@ behind an LB/cloudfront? How are you 'using' the certificate?

Comment: Oh, So ACM will only work with CloudFront or ACM, right?

Comment: Yes in your case on cloudfront or a elastic load balancer as answered by Philippe. For the complete list check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to add a Load Balancer (ALB) or a CloudFront Distribution in front of your EC2 instance since Certificates produced with ACM must be configured on these kind of components. Not possible with EC2. And it can not suggest where to use it.

Comment: Got it, ACM will only work with CloudFront or ACM, right?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html
Everything is here. 